# ASP.NET web form: display value coming from c# code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

I am working with Visual Studio 2019, where I am creating a web form. My code-behind pulls data from a database using a sql script. I have to display some of these fields in the web form.

For instance, `project_description` is one of the fields, which is stored as `ProjDesc` in my .cs file.

In the web form, I have a text box intended to display this field:

```
<td class="auto-style29"><b>Project description</b></td>
<td class="auto-style5"><asp:TextBox Text="<insert variable>" ID="txtProjTitle" runat="server" Width="768px" Height="26px" ReadOnly ="true" Enabled="false" CssClass="auto-style16"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Where it says `<insert variable>`, I tried to use the variable name `ProjDesc`, but this was highlighted because "it does not exist in the current context".

What's the correct way of recalling `ProjDesc` from my .aspx file? Does it have to go under the `Text` properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using web forms then one way to set the text of your textbox from the aspx is in an event of the web page, probably the same event that is firing the SQL script.

```
txtProjTitle.Text = ProjDesc
```

Comment: OK, this is done in the code-behind. Is this automatically recognised by the .aspx file?

Comment: @Zizzipupp Yes, the code-behind directly manipulates the aspx.